# Difference-in-difference and panel data models

Tags: repeated-measures, panel-data, random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model, difference-in-difference

I understand that according to the observations you have (two independent cross-sections in two or more time periods or the same individuals observed in two different periods), then difference-in-difference (DiD) models are employed by estimating, respectively, ordinary least squares (OLS) or a fixed-effects model.

My question is: in the second case, does it make sense to estimate a DiD model using a random-effects model?

Answer (score 1):

> I understand that according to the observations you have (two independent cross-sections in two or more time periods or the same individuals observed in two different periods), then difference-in-difference (DiD) models are employed by estimating, respectively, ordinary least squares (OLS) or a fixed-effects model.

You can use ordinary least squares (OLS) in *both* cases. In settings where you observe the same entities over multiple time periods, a *fixed effects* model is still estimated via OLS. Put differently, we simply employ the OLS estimator on the *time demeaned* data.

> My question is: in the second case, does it make sense to estimate a DiD model using a random-effects model?

I depends upon your research goals. But, in general, no.

A difference-in-differences model is, by design, a *within* model. In the simple setting involving two groups (i.e., treatment group versus control group) and two discrete time periods (i.e., before treatment versus after treatment), you're restricting attention to the *within-group* time variation in the outcomes.

If you want to proceed by treating your panel level effects as random, then be mindful you're estimating two different models. Under random effects, your estimand of interest is obtained by averaging the within *and* between-unit effects. As a consequence, you may now obtain estimates on certain *time-constant* covariates; they may be of substantive interest.

In practice, however, we worry the selection of units into a treatment or control condition is based upon some of these time-constant attributes. The choice of which units receive some intervention is often *not* under the control of the unit of observation. Employing DiD methods will help you overcome some of these selection concerns. This is why DiD is very popular in the evaluation of experimental programs aimed at aggregate level units.